# If the expense ratio of a MF is decreasing over past few years, does that indicate anything?

Tags: mutual-funds, expense-ratio, fund-manager

If a Mutual fund has expense ratio, which is continously decreasing over past few years, does that mean anything? Does it show growth/decline of the fund? Is it good time to invest ?

Answer (score 1):

I think all it means is that there is a market pressure for low-cost funds, and people move their investments from high-fee to lower-fee funds, so existing funds work on reducing their cost (or at least their fees).

This is happening all across the market, and not specific to any one fond.

Answer (score 0):

> Does it show growth/decline of the fund? Is it good time to invest ?

Not necessarily - it could mean that their expenses have remained constant while the value of the fund has increased, or it could mean that they purposely reduced their fees to remain competitive with other similar funds. Or something else.

In either case, it says nothing about the future value of the fund. The returns of a fund are driven much more by the performance of the assets than the expense ratio. The ratio is a *friction* to realized returns but it should not be the main investing factor.